# setting global CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1

Tags: php, ssl, curl

According to the php.net manual pages, http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php, the following is stated:

> CURLOPT_SSLVERSION One of CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT (0), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 (1), CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2 (2), CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 (3), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 (4), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 (5) or CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 (6).
>
> Note: Your best bet is to not set this and let it use the default. Setting it to 2 or 3 is very dangerous given the known vulnerabilities in SSLv2 and SSLv3.

How can I set `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` globally to `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1`.

Comment: you'd have to recompile php. or put a curl_setopt() somewhere central in your code. the only php.ini config option for curl is the path to the CA file.

Comment: If I opted to recompile, are there additional concerns I need to be aware of, and if so, what are they? If there are no additional concerns, what would I need to pass to php's compile variables/headers to properly compile `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` globally to `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1`. The issue I am having is that we have disabled SSLv3 on the server and set it to TLSv1 which is supposed to have fallbacks from TLSv1.2 to TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.0 however, when users try to access sites using browsers that do not support TLSv1.2 by default, they are being rejected.